# Equilibrium Point code challenge: recursion depth exceeded error -- what is mistake?

Tags: python, recursion

I am solving GeeksforGeeks problem [Equilibrium Point](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/equilibrium-point-1587115620/1):

> Given an array `A` of `n` positive numbers. The task is to find the first **equilibrium point** in an array. Equilibrium point in an array is a position such that the **sum** of elements **before** it is **equal** to the **sum** of elements **after** it.
>
> **Note:** Return equilibrium point in 1-based indexing. Return -1 if no such point exists.
>
> #### Your Task:
>
> The task is to complete the function `equilibriumPoint()` which takes the array and `n` as input parameters and returns the point of equilibrium.
>
> - **Expected Time Complexity:** O(n)
> - **Expected Auxiliary Space:** O(1)
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - 1 <= `n` <= 10<sup>5</sup>
> - 1 <= `A[i]` <= 10<sup>9</sup>

This is my code:

```
class Solution:
    # Complete this function
    #Function to find equilibrium point in the array.

    def equilibriumPoint(self,A, N):        

        def check(a,b,c,l,r):
            if(a>=b):
                return -1
            elif a<b:
                r=r-c[a]
                if l==r:
                    return a+1
                else:
                    l=l+c[a]
                return check(a+1,b,c,l,r)
                
        ls=0
        rs=sum(A)
        return check(0,N,A,ls,rs)
```

This passes for the example test cases, but when submitting I get this *maximum recursion depth exceeded* error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 55, in <module>
    main()
  line 49, in main
    print(ob.equilibriumPoint(A, N))
  line 30, in equilibriumPoint
    return check(0,N,A,ls,rs)
  line 21, in check
    return check(a+1,b,c,l,r)
  line 21, in check
    return check(a+1,b,c,l,r)
  line 21, in ................

Maximum recursion depth exceeded.
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real mistake in your code, but because for every next index you make a recursive call, the call stack will grow linear to the number of elements in the input list. As the constraints of this problem allow for inputs with 100,000 elements, the default stack limit will be reached long before all elements would have been processed.

Moreover, the code challenge description mentions that you should solve this challenge with O(1) space complexity, so that rules out your recursive approach -- as that requires O(n) stack space.

It is easy to convert your algorithm to an iterative one, and then it will pass.

Not the problem, but one-letter names like `a`, `b`, `c` make your code hard to read. Use descriptive names.

Here is your code adapted to become iterative (and with more telling names):

```
class Solution:
    def equilibriumPoint(self, numbers, size):        
        idx = 0
        left_sum = 0
        right_sum = sum(numbers)
        while idx < size:
            right_sum -= numbers[idx]
            if left_sum == right_sum:
                return idx + 1
            left_sum += numbers[idx]
            idx += 1
        return -1
```

Comment: Any feedback to this?

Comment: You're welcome. If you want you could [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), but it is completely optional :-)